# Groovy parallel sql queries

Tags: sql, multithreading, groovy, gpars

I'm trying to run parallel sql queries using GPars. But somehow it isn't working as I expected. Since I'm relatively new to groovy/java concurrency I'm not sure how to solve my issue.

I following code:

```
    def rows = this.sql.rows(
        "SELECT a_id, b_id FROM data_ids LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10"
    )
```

With this code I get a List of ids. Now I want the load the data for each loaded id and this should happen parallel to improve my performance, because I have a large database.

To get the detail data I use the following code:

```
GParsPool.withPool() {
result = rows.collectParallel {
    // 2. Get the data for each source and save it in an array.
    def tmpData = [:]
    def row = it

    sql.withTransaction {
        if (row.a_id != null) {
            tmpData.a = sql.firstRow("SELECT * FROM data_a WHERE id = '" + row.a_id + "'")
        }

        if (row.b_id != null) {
            tmpData.b = sql.firstRow("SELECT * FROM data_b WHERE id = '" + row.b_id + "'")
        }
    }

    return tmpData
}

// 3. Return the loaded data.
return result
```

Now I run the code and everything works fine except that the code isn't executed parallel. Using the JProfiler I can see that I have blocked threads and waiting threads, but 0 runnable threads.

Thanks for any help. I you need more information, I will provide them :)

Daniel

Comment: Are you reusing the same `Sql` object in all those threads? That's what it looks like, and I advise against that; I doubt JDBC connections are thread-safe. Also note that the queries block the current thread until the data is returned. So even if all of the threads have been started, once they hit the point of making the database call, they'll block. Try using a `Sql` instance per thread. The `Sql` class has a constructor which takes another `Sql` instance.

Comment: Or create a Sql instance using a data source. This will provide  gpars a pool of connections.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! I'm using a Sql instance for each thread.